# Differential equation of the second order

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Suppose I have the following differential equation:
$$f''(x)-2f(x)+CAe^{\sqrt Ax}\qquad (1)$$ with $c, A>0$.

How can I find the expression for $f(x)$.
In the homogeneous case ($f_H''(x)-2f_H(x)=0$) the solution would be $f_H(x)=e^{\sqrt 2x}$. Now I need to find a particular solution of (1). How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: It's not an equation .

Answer (score 1):

Your homogeneous solution is not ok... You should have found $f_H(x) = c_1 e^{\sqrt{2}x} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{2}x}$. You should also correct the differential equation in your post, maybe $f''- 2f + CA e^{\sqrt{Ax}}=0$?

Regarding the particular solution, if $A\ne 2$, just use $k e^{\sqrt{A} x}$ . If $A=2$, this will not work because the particular solution would satisfy the homogeneous equation, and the proper choice could be $k x e^{\sqrt{2}x}$.